# Alarm Manager not working in my code

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I wasted my whole day in search of solution for alarm manager to work. I am now too tired to search further. I have also read all questions and their answers in stackoverflow. Can any figure out my mistake in below code? i'll be very thank full to you.

Main Activity

```
public class DisplayWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;
    EditText link, date;
    Button insert;
    String[] receivedLink;
    ListView list;
    List<Model> ls_data;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayWebView.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DisplayWebView.this, 234324243, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (5 * 10), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Alarm Receiver

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("Testing","ok");

    }


}
```

Manifests

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.umama.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 <!--   <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>-->
    <receiver android:name="com.umama.WebView.AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" />
    <!--<receiver android:name="net.fusonic.testapp.receivers.TestAlarmReceiver"></receiver>-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".DisplayWebView">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Add `MyBroadcastReceiver` in `Manifests`

Comment: Previous comment is almost certainly the problem, but in the future explain "not working" more.  Not working could mean not firing at all, not firing at the right time, not firing repeatedly, etc.

Comment: MyBroadcastReceiver is a java class not an activity.. how to add it?

Comment: @PepperMint: Add `<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />` inside `application` tag

Comment: Thank You so much... Oh God.. such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 5):

To have some guarantees that works with all versions I advise you to do the following code. Also because of the [doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarms.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarms.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    } else {
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), recurringAlarm);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replace string with this:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

You have to replace 10 with 1000, because 5 * 10 = 0.05 second it is to short interval.

Pay attention that Android 5+ can use only interval more that 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (60 * 1000), pendingIntent); // 60 seconds after the current time
    }
}
```

Alarm Receiver

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        
        Log.e("Testing","ok");

    }

}
```

Manifests file

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.testapp">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
          
           <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" 
              android:enabled="true" />
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

For background working add this in main activity(if application remove in to recent)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```